# org.annolab.tt4j - Searching for a chunking tutorial

Tags: chunking, treetagger, tt4j

I'm trying to understand how to use the TreeTagger

http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/corplex/TreeTagger/

wrapped by tt4j

http://reckart.github.io/tt4j/

to chunk some text.

I can't find any tutorial.

Thanks for the help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503388/treetagger-installation-successful-but-cannot-open-par-file

Answer (score 0):

The tt4j page was updated with useful code to get started:

```
import org.annolab.tt4j.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class Example {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                // Point TT4J to the TreeTagger installation directory. The executable is expected
                // in the "bin" subdirectory - in this example at "/opt/treetagger/bin/tree-tagger"
                System.setProperty("treetagger.home", "/opt/treetagger");
                TreeTaggerWrapper tt = new TreeTaggerWrapper<String>();
                try {
                        tt.setModel("/opt/treetagger/models/english.par:iso8859-1");
                        tt.setHandler(new TokenHandler<String>() {
                                public void token(String token, String pos, String lemma) {
                                        System.out.println(token + "\t" + pos + "\t" + lemma);
                                }
                        });
                        tt.process(asList(new String[] { "This", "is", "a", "test", "." }));
                }
                finally {
                        tt.destroy();
                }
        }
}
```

A pom.xml (Maven) like this should be enough to get it working:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.annolab.tt4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.annolab.tt4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>gk2go</groupId>
  <artifactId>gk</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>gk</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
</project>
```

All code above was adapted, so not tested as-is.